# How can I copy an XML structure into another one except some attributes or nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

with the XML structure below:

```
<root foo1="bar1" foo2="bar2" foo3="bar3">
    <foo1 foo1="bar1" />

    <data>
        <foo1>bar1</foo1>
        <foo2>bar2</foo2>
        <foo3>bar3</foo3>
    </data>
</root>
```

I would like to copy this XML structure into another one with some exception on attributes and/or node() names and get the following
result using XSLT 1.0:

```
<root foo1="bar1" foo2="bar2">    
    <data>
        <foo1>bar1</foo1>
        <foo3>bar3</foo3>
    </data>
</root>
```

My rules are:

1) Copy every root attributes except foo3

2) Copy every child `nodes()` unless the ones named foo1 and foo2

My actual XSL stylesheet. I managed to get the root attributes restriction working :

```
<xsl:template match="root">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="./@*">
            <xsl:variable name="name" select="name()" />

            <xsl:if test="name() != 'foo3'">
                <xsl:attribute name="{$name}"><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>


    </root>
</xsl:template>
```

Also, one harder question:
What if I want to matches my attributes and nodes dynamically. I would like to specify server-side what
attributes and `nodes()` I would like to remove. It's probably like generating a string that is then used in the `<xsl:if>`. I don't know if that's even possible.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what your second question is. In the limit it's possible to generate an XSL stylesheet on the fly (and you can use XSLT to do this) but I doubt you need to go this far

Comment: Hi, I could use the PHP function `registerPHPFunctions()` and call a custom function in XSLT to extract the `nodes()`/attributes I would like to exclude from my copy using: `<xsl:variable name="dynamic"><xsl:value-of select="php:function('foo', 'foo')" /></xsl:variable>` This way I dont have to modify everytime the XSLT. Only my PHP function `foo()`.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a fully dynamic, parameterized solution. :)

Comment: +1 I enjoyed answering this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to copy this XML
>   structure into another one with some
>   exception [...]
>
> My rules are:
>
> 1) Copy every root attributes except
>   foo3
>
> 2) Copy every child nodes() unless the
>   ones named foo1 and foo2

**Update from comments**:

> Hi, this almost work. Except that
>   data/foo1 should be copied

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="root/@foo3|root/foo1|foo2"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<root foo1="bar1" foo2="bar2">
    <data>
        <foo1>bar1</foo1>
        <foo3>bar3</foo3>
    </data>
</root>
```

**Note**: Overwriting identity rule with empty templates

With the node names in parameter, this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:param name="pStrip" select="'root/@foo3|root/foo1|foo2'"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
        <xsl:param name="pStripPaths" select="concat($pStrip,'|')"/>
        <xsl:param name="pNodePath">
            <xsl:call-template name="path"/>
            <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        </xsl:param>
        <xsl:variable name="vStripPath"
                      select="substring-before($pStripPaths,'|')"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not($pStripPaths)">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains($pNodePath,concat('/',$vStripPath,'|'))"/>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:call-template name="identity">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pStripPaths"
                                    select="substring-after($pStripPaths,'|')"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="pNodePath" select="$pNodePath"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node()" name="path" mode="path">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="parent::*" mode="path"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('/',
                                     substring('@',
                                               1 div (count(.|../@*)
                                                      = count(../@*))),
                                     name())"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<root foo1="bar1" foo2="bar2">
    <data>
        <foo1>bar1</foo1>
        <foo3>bar3</foo3>
    </data>
</root>
```

**Note**: In XML, the element name refers to the schema, mostly defining the hierarchie position, but yours is not the case.

**Edit**: Just for fun, an XSLT 2.0 solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:local="http://localhost">
    <xsl:param name="pStrip" select="'root/@foo3|root/foo1|foo2'"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[local:match($pStrip,.)]|@*[local:match($pStrip,.)]"/>
    <xsl:function name="local:match" as="xs:boolean">
        <xsl:param name="pStripPaths" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:param name="pNode" as="item()"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vNodePath"
                      select="string-join(($pNode
                                            /ancestor::node()
                                             /name(),
                                           if ($pNode instance of attribute())
                                           then concat('@',name($pNode))
                                           else name($pNode)),
                                           '/')"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="some $path in tokenize($pStripPaths,'\|')
                                  satisfies ends-with($vNodePath,
                                                      concat('/',$path))"/>
    </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Edit 2**: All the stylesheet following the same string pattern.

Comment: Hi, this almost work. Except that data/foo1 should be copied. But I am aware that it might not be possible (or atleast without use of  recursive templates). I might change my original question so your solutions be accepted. Any idea how I could use dynamic value in the template match attribute? `<xsl:template match="$varname" />` with `<xsl:variable name="dynamic">root/@foo3|foo1|foo2</xsl:variable>` doesn't work.

Comment: Also, I dont know why but when I view-source using IE8, I get the the same result as your output but IE can't handle it. It looks like some `\n` (newline) should be added to be a valid XML file. This is an example of what is generated: #1: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>CRLF` #2: `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="toXML.xslt"?><root foo1="bar1" foo2="bar2"> CRLF`

Answer (score 1):

You can use XPath to simplify your selection:

```
<xsl:for-each select="./@*[not(name()='foo3')]">
```

You then don't have to test for the names. You can do a similar thing for the elements:

```
*[not(name()='foo2')]
```

Comment: Or, `@*[not(self::foo3)]` and `*[not(self::foo2)]`.

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation accepts a parameter with the XPath expressions to all elements/attributes that should be deleted**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
 >
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="pDeletes">
  <element>/root/data/foo2</element>
  <element>/root/foo1</element>
  <attribute>/root/@foo3</attribute>
 </xsl:param>

 <xsl:variable name="vDeletes"
  select="msxsl:node-set($pDeletes)"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:variable name="vPath">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="buildPath"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:if test="not(string($vPath) = $vDeletes/element)">
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:variable name="vPath">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="buildPath"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:if test="not(string($vPath) = $vDeletes/attribute)">
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*" mode="buildPath">
  <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('/',name())"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vprecSiblings"
     select="count(preceding-sibling::*[name()=name(current())])"/>

    <xsl:if test="$vprecSiblings">
     <xsl:value-of select="concat('[', $vprecSiblings, ']')"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@*" mode="buildPath">
  <xsl:variable name="vParentPath">
    <xsl:apply-templates select=".." mode="buildPath"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:value-of select="concat($vParentPath, '/@', name())"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<root foo1="bar1" foo2="bar2" foo3="bar3">
    <foo1 foo1="bar1" />
    <data>
        <foo1>bar1</foo1>
        <foo2>bar2</foo2>
        <foo3>bar3</foo3>
    </data>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<root foo1="bar1" foo2="bar2">
    <data>
        <foo1>bar1</foo1>
        <foo3>bar3</foo3>
    </data>
</root>
```

**Do note**:

1. **Each XPath expression that identifies a node to be deleted, is the string value of an `element` or `attribute` child of a global, externally provided parameter**. The location steps of any such expression contain the name of the element and in the predicate part its ordinal number among all identically named siblings. If this is the first element the predicate should not be soecified. For attributes, the last location step contains exactly `"@"AttributeName`, where `AttributeName` is the name of the attribute.
2. **The `xxx:node-set()` extension function is here only for demo purpuses**. In practice, the `$pDeletes` parameter will be provided externally and there is no need to apply the `xxx:node-set()` function on it.
3. **All the XPath expressions could be provided in one string (using a better delimiter than the `|` XPath union operator :) ), but this may be less efficient than having each expression in a separate element.** In the latter case elements or attributes can be searched separately and also if efficiency matters the expressions can be indexed, say by element or attribute name, thus providing very fast, sublinear search time.

Comment: Hi, it works when I use client-side transformation but it fails when using the PHP xsltProcessor(). Indeed I haven't mentioned I was using PHP in my question but I mentioned it in my comment under my question. Any tips to make it work with PHP? The error I get is `function node-set not found`. Anyway, I'm always surprised by your XSLT skills. You are my hero!

Comment: @Cybrix: Find which namespace is used for the xxx:node-set() extension in your XSLT processor (I think it must be LibXSLT). In practice, the parameter will be set externally and the xxx:node-set() extension will not be necessary.

Comment: @Cybrix: I added to my answer an explanation how this solution is better and faster than a solution in which all expressions are stuffed in a single string.